# Case/switch not activating onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, switch-statement

I'm recreating the Fallout terminal game using vanilla Javascript---one of the game's main elements is comparing the word you selected to the word that the computer chose.

> The hacking game is similar to Mastermind, a board game. You will be
>   presented with a list of words, all of the same character length...One
>   of the words is the correct password, and your goal is to guess it.
>
> You choose a word by clicking on it. If you didn't guess correctly,
>   the terminal will display "x/y correct" where x is the number of
>   correct letters, and y is the word length. A letter is correct only if
>   it is in the right spot.

I got the compare aspect working in the console and I was recently able to get the case 0 part to show up on screen, but when I click on another word it doesn't load the next line "Three attempts remaining."

I'm not sure if it's something obvious with my code or if I'm missing something altogether, so I thought I'd ask about it here.

The .js file:

```
var giantArray = []; // combination of var garbage and var words

var goalWord = ""; // word that the computer chose to be the "goal"  // STRING

var userWord = ""; // the current word that the user selected // STRING

var playerAttempts = 0; // how many past attempts the user has made
```

---

```
var shuffledWords = shuffle(words); // randomly pick an index between 0 and 35

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  createAttempt();

});
```

---

```
function createAttempt() {
  switch (playerAttempts) {
    case 0:
      attempts.innerHTML = "Four attempts remaining. [] [] [] []";
      break;
    case 1:
      attempts.innerHTML += "Three attempts remaining. [] [] []<br>";
      break;
    case 2:
      attempts.innerHTML += "Two attempts remaining. [] []<br>";
      break;
    case 3:
      attempts.innerHTML += "!! Warning: Lock out pending !! []<br>";
      break;
    default:
      attempts.innerHTML += "This terminal has been locked. Please contact your administrator.";
      break;
  }
  playerAttempts++;

}

createAttempt();

function clickFunc(evt) {
  if (evt.target.innerText.slice(1) === goalWord) { // need .slice method to eliminate space character
  console.log('Welcome back' + '. ');
  } else {
  console.log('try again')
  }
}
```

clickFunk();

The HTML:

```
   <div class="panels"> <!-- level 3 -->

        <div class="top-text"> <!-- level 4 -->
          <ul>
            <li>______ INDUSTRIES (TM) TERMALINK PROTOCOL</li>
            <li>ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="attempts"></div> <!-- level 4 -->
```

Comment: who is calling `clickFunc`?

Comment: where is `playerAttempts` defined?

Comment: @JaromandaX playerAttempts is defined at the top. I forgot to add it to this question but I'll do so now.

Comment: @brk I didn't realize the clickFunc call was missing---I added it but I'm getting an error message (Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
    at clickFunc), and when I add in arguments I get similar errors. I'll shuffle a few things around and see what I can do.

Comment: you're only calling `createAttempt` once?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Hi, I called it again under "DOMContentLoaded" but now I can't get the words to appear. :|

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I moved the function that creates the words up and now the words are appearing, but when I click on a word "Three attempts remaining" appears right next to the "Four attempts" one.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Just fixed that problem. But thanks for listening to my rants :)

Comment: @Tsardines check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`but when I click on another word it doesn't load the next line "Three attempts remaining."` is the keyword of your question. It loads the first time, because you're calling it once. You're not calling it again when you actually click on something (which invokes your click function). You need to call it in your click function to re-call the function. as such:

```
createAttempt();

function clickFunc(evt) {
  createAttempt();
  if (evt.target.innerText.slice(1) === goalWord) { // need .slice method to eliminate space character
  console.log('Welcome back' + '. ');

  } else {
  console.log('try again')
  }
}
```

Now you will find that it will print each time you click depending on what the value is for the switch.

**UPDATE**

Not seeing anywhere in the code you posted which actually invokes the clickFunc call. You need to tell it what function to call when you click something. So in your target element, just set the `onclick` attribute to point to your  function, as such:

`onclick="clickFunc(event)"`